# How to pull images from a secure registry without copying CA to each host?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, docker-registry, certificate-authority

I am running a secure private docker registry on a machine (server) within my local network. My kubernetes and helm clients are running on another machine (host).

I am using a Certification Authority (CA) in the server machine in order to verify https pull requests from the host. That is why I am copying the registry's Certificate Authority (CA) to the host [as mentioned here](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/#use-self-signed-certificates):

> Instruct every Docker daemon to trust that certificate. For Linux:
>
> Copy the domain.crt file to
> /etc/docker/certs.d/myregistrydomain.com:5000/ca.crt on every Docker
> host. You do not need to restart Docker

Even though this solution works as a charm, but only for few nodes.

From kubernetes or HELM perspective, is there a way to generate a secret or stating username/password inside the charts. Sot that, when 1000 hosts exist, there will be no need to copy the CA to every and each single host?

Server and hosts run Centos7

Comment: So you're looking for an easy way an attacker can inject a server with an invalid certificate and get any client to blindly trust it?

Comment: @BMitch : I was thinking of an easy way to group requests from a specific network or applications so that I don't need to generate keys for each client separately !!

Comment: Can you update the question with details of why you are generating client keys yourself? Https typically only cares about the server verification, which requires the server certificate, or the ca that signs it, to be trusted by the client.

Comment: @BMitch: Is it better rephrased now ?